# Main road: 大通り vs 幹線道路

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I have found two words for "main road":

- 大通り
- 幹線道路

What are the differing nuances of these? Is one more commonly used?

Comment: I fixed an obvious typo (観戦 → 幹線). [観戦](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A6%B3%E6%88%A6) makes no sense here.

Comment: Thank you @naruto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**大通り** is closer to "main street" (of a tourist spot, downtown, etc.). It has a lot of shops, and it is typically not longer than a few kilometers. You can find many pedestrians on an 大通り. Typical examples include Champs-Élysées and Broadway.

**幹線道路** refers to roads that connect major locations and are important in terms of transporting people and goods. The roadside of a 幹線道路 does not have to be commercially developed. Although there is no particular strict legal criterion, it at least includes highways, and it also includes smaller roads as long as they are recognized and used by most people living in a city. One typical example in Japan is 環状七号線 ([video](https://youtu.be/hMYHyPJIXuY)), a 52 km road running through peripheral areas of Tokyo.